# Infer 'this' pointer type when called from derived class?

Tags: c++, templates, types, type-deduction

I have a method in a baseclass that needs the type passed to it for some type-related operations (lookup, size, and some method invocation). Currently it looks like this:

```
class base
{
    template<typename T>
    void BindType( T * t ); // do something with the type
};

class derived : public base
{
    void foo() { do_some_work BindType( this ); } 
};

class derivedOther : public base 
{
    void bar() { do_different_work... BindType( this ); } 
};
```

However, I wonder if there's a way to get the caller's type without having to pass this so that my callpoint code becomes:

```
class derived : public base
{
  void foo() { BindType(); } 
};
```

Without the explicit this pointer. I know that I could supply the template parameters explicitly as `BindType<derived>()`, but is there a way to somehow extract the type of the caller in some other way?

Comment: This is a typical use case for the CRTP http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4173254/what-is-the-curiously-recurring-template-pattern-crtp

Comment: use `typeid(*this)` in the base class?

Comment: @davmac typeid doesn't give me the type in a way I can use to .., say call sizeof(T) or T::SomeFunction() - it only gives me the typeid.

Comment: @Steven right, but your question says only that you need it for "some type-to-index lookup code" and for that purpose it should be fine.

Comment: @davmac fair enough - I will update the question.

Comment: @skypjack Interesting - I didn't realize that we can now templatize the constructor. This kind-of works.

Comment: @Steven Added an answer with all the details. Let me know if it's clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It will not work as you expect**

The result of `foo()` might be different of what you expect:

```
class derived : public base           // <= YOU ARE IN CLASS DERIVED
{
public:
    void foo() { BindType( this ); }  // <= SO this IS OF TYPE POINTER TO DERIVED
};
```

The template paramter is deducted at **compile time**, so that it will be `derived*`.  If you would call `foo()` from a class `derived_once_more` derived from `derived`, it would still use the type `derived*`.

[Online demo](http://ideone.com/OJXJMW)

**But you can get rid of the dummy parameter***

You may use `decltype(this)` to represent the typename of a variable.  It's still defined at compile time:

```
class base
{
public: 
    template<typename T>
    void BindType( ) 
    { 
         cout << typeid(T*).name()<<endl;  // just to show the type 
    }
    virtual ~base() {};                    // for typeid() to work 
};
class derived : public base
{
public: 
    void foo() { BindType<decltype(this)>( ); } 
};
```

[Online demo](http://ideone.com/TSgGBf)

**Edit: other alternatives**

As template parameters need to be provided at compile-time and not a run time, you can use:

- template parameter deduction (your first code snippet)
- `decltype (see above)`
- if you intend to add this in all the derived classes you could use a macro  to get it done, using one of the above mentionned solution
- you could use the CRTP pattern (already explained in another answer).

Comment: Yes - I agree that the type of this is specific to the calling context, even if called from a derived class. I think that's okay as I am mostly worried about having greater type context than base. It's a fair criticism. the decltype(this) certainly removes the dummy parameter, but it requires more typing at the callpoint.

Comment: As much as all of the examples and solutions provided are interesting, I am actually going to go with my original solution! BindToType(this) is easy to read and doesn't require people who are new to modern C++ to understand what decltype does for us. Christophe's solution covers some of the issues and solutions, so I think it's the best choice for a good answer. Thanks all.

Answer (score 4):

There's no magical way to get the caller's type, but you can use CRTP (as a comment mentions) in order to automate this behavior, at the cost of a bit of code complexity:

```
class base
{
    template<typename T>
    void BindType(); // do something with the type
};

template <class T>
class crtper : base
{
     void BindDerived { BindType<T>(); }
}

class derived : public crtper<derived>
{
    void foo() { do_some_work BindDerived(); } 
};

class derivedOther : public crtper<derivedOther>
{
    void bar() { do_different_work... BindDerived(); } 
};
```

Edit: I should mention, I would kind have expected that `foo` would be a virtual function, defined without implementation in `base`. That way you would be able to trigger the action directly from the interface. Although maybe you have that in your real code, but not in your example. In any case, this solution is perfectly compatible with this.

Edit2: After question edit, edited to clarify that solution still applies.

Comment: I don't think my sample was clear -- foo is simple a method defined in the derived class specific to the derived class; the use of BindType there isn't consistent across all derived classes of base.

Comment: @Steven My solution still works, just need to change the names of things. See updated code.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to avoid `BindType<derived>()`, consider (a bit verbose, I agree) `BindType<std::remove_reference<decltype(*this)>::type>();` to avoid passing a parameter. It gets resolved at compile-time and avoids run-time penalties.

```
class base
{
protected:
    template<typename T>
    void BindType() { cout << typeid(T).name() << endl; } // do something with the type
};

class derived : public base
{
public:
    void foo()
    {
        BindType<std::remove_reference<decltype(*this)>::type>();
    }
};
```

Comment: I don't see the advantage of this over just explicitly specifying `derived` in the angle brackets (as OP mentioned), unless you are planning to use a macro or copy and paste.

Comment: @NirFriedman I think agree - this is more wordy. I suspect most compilers would 'do the right thing' and optimize it away.

Comment: @Steven Well, my concern is not related to the performance of the code. In all likelihood, the OP's code is also very likely to get fully optimized anyhow (a function called once usually gets inlined, and once the function is inlined it's game over). I'm really only thinking about code clarity.

Comment: @NirFriedman I see no advantage if the type name (`derived`) is easily accessible in the given context.

Comment: `decltype(*this)` is `derived&`, not `derived`.

Comment: @skypjack Thanks! Updated.

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution that avoids the intermediate class of the CRTP follows:

```
class base {
    using func_t = void(*)(void *);

    template<typename T>
    static void proto(void *ptr) {
        T *t = static_cast<T*>(ptr);
        (void)t;
        // do whatever you want...
    }

protected:
    inline void bindType() {
        func(this);
    }

public:
    template<typename T>
    base(T *): func{&proto<T>} {}

private:
    func_t func;
};

struct derived1: base {
    derived1(): base{this} {}

    void foo() {
         // ...
        bindType();
    }
};

struct derived2: base {
    derived2(): base{this} {}

    void bar() {
        // ...
        bindType();
    }
};

int main() {
    derived1 d1;
    d1.foo();

    derived2 d2;
    d2.bar();
}
```

The basic idea is to exploit the fact that the `this` pointers in the constructor of the derived classes are of the desired types.
They can be passed as a parameter of the constructor of the base class and used to specialize a function template that *do the dirty job* behind the hood.
The type of the derived class is actually erased in the base class once the constructor returns. Anyway, the specialization of `proto` contains that information and it can cast the `this` pointer of the base class to the right type.

This works fine as long as there are few functions to be specialized.
In this case there is only one function, so it applies to the problem pretty well.

---

You can add a `static_assert` to add a constraint on `T`, as an example:

```
template<typename T>
base(T *t): func{&proto<T>} {
    static_assert(std::is_base_of<base, T>::value, "!");
}
```

It requires to include the `<type_traits>` header.